# Large images not being uploaded with Intervention in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, intervention

In my laravel setup, I'm currently using Intervention for image uploads.

However, at the moment, images above the size of 3MB are not being uploaded.

`ini_get('upload_max_filesize')` and `ini_get('post_max_size')` give me back 5MB and 8MB respectively.

My image save controller is as follows:

```
public function saveImage(Request $request) {
   if (Auth::check()) {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'title' => 'required|max:50|min:2|alpha_num',
            'mature' => 'required',
            'categorie' => 'required',
            'description' => 'string|max:2000',
            'fileUpload' => 'required',
        ]); 

        $galleryConfirmation = Gallery::where('id', $request->get('gallerySelect'))->value('created_by');

        if (Auth::user()->id == $galleryConfirmation || $galleryConfirmation == 0 || $galleryConfirmation == null ) {

            $file = $request->file('fileUpload');

            if ($file->getClientSize() > 3999999) {
                dd("nooooo");
            }

            $filename = time() . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension() ;

            Image::make($file)->save( public_path('/uploads/artistUploads/' . $filename ) );

            $thumb = Image::make($file);
            $thumb->resize(null, 200, function ($constraint) {
                $constraint->aspectRatio();
            });
            $thumb->save( public_path('/uploads/artistUploads/thumbs/' . $filename , 60) );

            $images = new Images;

            $images->title = $request->input('title');
            $images->file_name = $filename;
            $images->file_size = $file->getClientSize();
            $images->file_mime = $file->getClientMimeType();
            $images->file_path = 'uploads/artistUploads/' . $filename;
            $images->description = $request->input('description');
            $images->mature = $request->input('mature');
            $images->categorie = $request->get('categorie');
            if (Auth::user()->id == $galleryConfirmation) {
                $images->gallery_id = $request->get('gallerySelect');
            }
            $images->created_by = Auth::user()->id;

            $images->save();

            return redirect()->back()->with('info', 'Image successfully uploaded.');    

        }

        if (!Auth::user()->id == $galleryConfirmation) {
            return redirect()->back()->with('info', 'Something went wrong');
        }

   }
}
```

When uploading a file of 3MB or higher, I get back only a white page. Furthermore, my `laravel.log` file is not showing any errors.

By using `dd('test');` after each line, I was able to find out that the crash happens at this line:

> Image::make($file)->save( public_path('/uploads/artistUploads/' .
>   $filename ) );

Help?

**EDIT:**

There was an error in the apache error log:

> [Mon Oct 31 04:17:31.109685 2016] [:error] [pid 13024:tid 1596] [client ::1:55986] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in C:\xampp\htdocs\series\commend-me\CommendMe\vendor\intervention\image\src\Intervention\Image\Gd\Decoder.php on line 119, referer: http://localhost/submit

This error shows up when trying to upload a picture above 3MB.

I raised the memory limit in my php.ini file, however I still find this rather strange. Why is this taking up so much memory? Is this normal?

Comment: This sounds like a server configuration matter. I ran into something that sounds similar, from the surface, with IIS once. (i.e. the web app had a larger size allowed than the server level configuration would allow.)

Comment: Well, I'm on XAMPP. I wouldn't really know what to change, other than the php.ini file

Comment: Perhaps you could speak with a server admin to see if they can assist with the sleuthing?

Comment: I wouldn't really know where to begin.

Comment: Once you get a hold of the server admin, I would begin by reviewing with him, what you've seen so far, for the reported values, by php, and the behavior when uploading 3MB files. Then I would ask "Is there another, smaller, upload file size limit being imposed by Apache?" and if the answer is "yes" "Can we increase it?"

Comment: I don't have a server admin, or a server for that matter. This is just on localhost through xampp.

Comment: Are there any errors in your php error log?

Comment: try `$request->file('photo')->isValid()` please. That may be caused by php max upload size.

Comment: There is indeed an error in my php error log! I've updated the main post to reflect that error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Image operations tend to be quite memory exhausting because image handling libraries usually 'unpack' all the pixels to memory. A JPEG file of 3MB can thus easily grow to 60MB in memory and that's when you've probably hit the memory limit allocated for PHP.

As far I remember, XAMP only allocates 128 MB RAM for PHP.

Check your php.ini and increase the memory limit, e.g.:

```
memory_limit = 512MB
```

Comment: Thanks, it's solving my problem